# inner_hit definition with the name [TypeName] already exists. Use a different inner_hit name

Tags: elasticsearch

I have had a search query with the following payload :-

```
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "filter": {
            "and": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "@timestamp": {
                             "gte": "2015-01-01||/d",
                             "lte": "2016-01-01||/d"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "or": [
                        {
                            "has_child": {
                                "type": "TypeName",
                                "filter": {
                                    "term": {
                                        "eventType.raw": "some-event"
                                    }
                                },
                                "inner_hits": {
                                    "_source": "@timestamp"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "not": {
                                "has_child": {
                                    "type": "TypeName",
                                    "filter": {
                                        "term": {
                                            "eventType.raw": "some-event"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "inner_hits": {
                                        "_source": "@timestamp"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

and this was working fine with elasticsearch 1.7 but with the latest stable version 2.3.3 of elasticsearch it does not quite work and fails with the following response :-

```
        "reason": {
           "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
           "reason": "inner_hit definition with the name [TypeName] already exists. Use a different inner_hit name"
        }
```

The logs shows the following stack trace :-

```
nested: IllegalArgumentException[inner_hit definition with the name [TypeName] already exists. Use a different inner_hit name];
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:855)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:654)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:620)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:371)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:368)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:365)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportRequestHandler.messageReceived(TransportRequestHandler.java:33)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:75)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:376)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: inner_hit definition with the name [TypeName] already exists. Use a different inner_hit name
    at org.elasticsearch.search.fetch.innerhits.InnerHitsContext.addInnerHitDefinition(InnerHitsContext.java:69)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.addInnerHits(QueryParseContext.java:218)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.HasChildQueryParser.parse(HasChildQueryParser.java:155)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerFilter(QueryParseContext.java:277)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.NotQueryParser.parse(NotQueryParser.java:69)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerQuery(QueryParseContext.java:250)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerFilter(QueryParseContext.java:263)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.OrQueryParser.parse(OrQueryParser.java:69)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerQuery(QueryParseContext.java:250)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerFilter(QueryParseContext.java:263)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.AndQueryParser.parse(AndQueryParser.java:69)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerQuery(QueryParseContext.java:250)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerFilter(QueryParseContext.java:263)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.FilteredQueryParser.parse(FilteredQueryParser.java:79)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerQuery(QueryParseContext.java:250)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.innerParse(IndexQueryParserService.java:320)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parse(IndexQueryParserService.java:223)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parse(IndexQueryParserService.java:218)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryParseElement.parse(QueryParseElement.java:33)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:838)
    ... 12 more
```

Any idea what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the answer by Martijn Van on elasticsearch community at https://discuss.elastic.co/t/inner-hits-queries-break-from-1-7-to-2-3-in-elasticsearch/54242/4?u=siddharthgoel88 .

> The problem is that you have two inner hits definitions in your
>   request that use the same name. The default name is based on the type
>   inside of the has_child query. You can provide a custom name by
>   specifying name field inside the inner_hits definition. The inner_hit
>   name is important here, because that is used in the response to
>   identify to what inner_hit definition the inner hits belong to.
>
> The following request should work:
>
> ```
> {
> "query": {
>     "filtered": {
>         "filter": {
>             "and": [
>                 {
>                     "range": {
>                         "@timestamp": {
>                              "gte": "2015-01-01||/d",
>                              "lte": "2016-01-01||/d"
>                         }
>                     }
>                 },
>                 {
>                     "or": [
>                         {
>                             "has_child": {
>                                 "type": "TypeName",
>                                 "filter": {
>                                     "term": {
>                                         "eventType.raw": "some-event"
>                                     }
>                                 },
>                                 "inner_hits": {
>                                     "_source": "@timestamp",
>                                     "name" : "inner_hit1"
>                                 }
>                             }
>                         },
>                         {
>                             "not": {
>                                 "has_child": {
>                                     "type": "TypeName",
>                                     "filter": {
>                                         "term": {
>                                             "eventType.raw": "some-event"
>                                         }
>                                     },
>                                     "inner_hits": {
>                                         "_source": "@timestamp",
>                                         "name" : "inner_hit2"
>                                     }
>                                 }
>                             }
>                         }
>                     ]
>                 }
>             ]
>         }
>     }
> }
> }
> ```